# Redeploying the changes to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

I am new to dot net web services and I have created a web service which I was somehow able to deploy to IIS.

Now, I've made some code changes to it and again clicked on "Created Deployment Package". Should I just copy paste these new dlls to the location where my Web service is deployed or is there some-other way to redeploy the code changes for web service to IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes simple and easy is copy the dll to iis and you are done, even you may not require deployment package.

in general i publish the site to a local folder and then copy it to server.

but in case you are using local machine iis you can publish directly to respective iis folder.

Comment: @user1705851 glad to know it worked , would you mind marking this as correct answer . (this would help any other user with same problem ) . You also should go to you other questions asked and if there is answer that worked mark it (green tick) to confirm .